# Cannot connect to Localhost after connecting to remote host in mysql

Tags: mysql

I am new to MySQL. I downloaded the Zip version of MySQL 5.6.23-win32. I was able to connect to Localhost at 127.0.0.1 and use the database. Later I installed MySQL in another computer in the same network. I tried to connect to the MySQL installed in the second computer from the first one by giving all GRANTS to the first computer and using the command
mysql -u root -h 192.168.1.120 (where 192.168.1.120  was the ip of remote computer)
and I was able to connect to that computer and access MySQL. 
But after that, when I tried to connect the Localhost in the first computer, it shows "Can't connect to MySQL server on localhost".
I am still able to access MySQL on the remote computer. I tried to revoke all GRANTS and privileges to the first computer in remote computer and tried to connect to localhost. But still its not working.

Could you please advise me how to fix it? Appreciate your help.

Comment: Do you still have a localhost root user?

Comment: Check carefully all mysql settings on machine that You can't connect. Maybe mysql is using different port than default `3306` or maybe the port is blocked ( by router ) or in any other way ( firewall ).

Comment: @Michal PrzybylowiczI: checked it. Port 3306 is used by mysql only. I  did telnet remotehost 3306 and it was connecting. But telnet localhost 3306 failed.

Comment: Try those commands:
`mysql -u root -p[pass] -h [your_win_ip]`
`mysql -u root -p[pass] -h localhost`
`mysql -u root -p[pass] -h 127.0.0.1`
If neither works - then it is problem with root user I think...

Answer (score 0):

I have very similar problem with `| @@version | 5.1.54 |`.
I was able to connect to `mysql as "-u root -h 127.0.0.1 -p`".
Next without any other change I did
`grant_remote_access "IP_addr"` and
`grant all privileges on *.* to 'root'@'IP_addr' identified by 'root_pwd';`.
Since then I cannot connect locally using `-h 127.0.0.1`.
I can only connect again locally using
`mysql -u root -h "IP_addr" -p`,
that is network IP of the same local host.
For me this smells pretty straightforward as a bug. Dmitri